# Tensorflow deepID CNN model training accuracy decrease after steadily climb to 50-60% acc

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, convolution

I am trainning a CNN model for classification of 100 classes base on 2000 samples. To avoid overfitting I make argumentation of 2k samples to 20k by noise and rotation etc.

The result confuse me because the training acc climb steadily to 40-60%, and drop rapidly to lower than 10%. This happened for several times, at first I change the learning rate to check if this would help. But even I set lr as low as 0.001, this situation exits.

I use dropout at 0.2-0.5 and regulation in conv and pooling layers. And I also use batch normalization in resdual block.

```
Epoch 396/1000 - loss: 0.695151 - acc: 0.422    validation acc: 0.36
Epoch 397/1000 - loss: 0.694972 - acc: 0.416    validation acc: 0.34
Epoch 398/1000 - loss: 0.698717 - acc: 0.152    validation acc: 0.12
Epoch 399/1000 - loss: 0.698495 - acc: 0.14 validation acc: 0.14
Epoch 400/1000 - loss: 0.696137 - acc: 0.344    validation acc: 0.26
Epoch 401/1000 - loss: 0.694856 - acc: 0.44 validation acc: 0.28
Epoch 402/1000 - loss: 0.694578 - acc: 0.454    validation acc: 0.32
Epoch 403/1000 - loss: 0.694385 - acc: 0.464    validation acc: 0.34
Epoch 404/1000 - loss: 0.694594 - acc: 0.434    validation acc: 0.36
Epoch 405/1000 - loss: 0.695077 - acc: 0.376    validation acc: 0.36
Epoch 406/1000 - loss: 0.694583 - acc: 0.426    validation acc: 0.36
Epoch 407/1000 - loss: 0.695255 - acc: 0.39 validation acc: 0.32
Epoch 408/1000 - loss: 0.694716 - acc: 0.432    validation acc: 0.34
Epoch 409/1000 - loss: 0.694765 - acc: 0.42 validation acc: 0.36
Epoch 410/1000 - loss: 0.694443 - acc: 0.446    validation acc: 0.36
Epoch 411/1000 - loss: 0.694334 - acc: 0.462    validation acc: 0.38
Epoch 412/1000 - loss: 0.69475 - acc: 0.404 validation acc: 0.36
Epoch 413/1000 - loss: 0.694607 - acc: 0.428    validation acc: 0.36
Epoch 414/1000 - loss: 0.69983 - acc: 0.022 validation acc: 0.02
Epoch 415/1000 - loss: 0.698023 - acc: 0.014    validation acc: 0.02
Epoch 416/1000 - loss: 0.697584 - acc: 0.012    validation acc: 0.0
Epoch 417/1000 - loss: 0.697573 - acc: 0.01 validation acc: 0.0
Epoch 418/1000 - loss: 0.697533 - acc: 0.01 validation acc: 0.0
Epoch 419/1000 - loss: 0.697563 - acc: 0.014    validation acc: 0.0
Epoch 420/1000 - loss: 0.697468 - acc: 0.038    validation acc: 0.0
Epoch 421/1000 - loss: 0.697476 - acc: 0.026    validation acc: 0.12
Epoch 422/1000 - loss: 0.697426 - acc: 0.04 validation acc: 0.12
Epoch 423/1000 - loss: 0.697475 - acc: 0.078    validation acc: 0.12
Epoch 424/1000 - loss: 0.697317 - acc: 0.074    validation acc: 0.08
```

Many thanks if there is any suggestion to this problem.

Comment: Looks like it is overfitting.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I am confused if it is overfitting, why didn't the training acc improve further? Gradient descent should remain the acc and loss at the same level if no improvement.

Comment: It probably is overfitting to a few, possibly unusual or otherwise problematic, training instances. This seems to happen frequently, and people just stop training further once the accuracy begins to drop. I'm not certain it is understood why and when this happens.

Comment: But there recently was a paper that observed two phases when training NNs. Maybe that provides some insight into these problems: http://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/05/two-phases-gradient-descent-deep-learning.html